# Problem with the date format in a column of my DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a column which contains dates as string objects, however the dates are not all in the same format. Some are MM/YYYY or YYYY. I would like them to be all YYYY, and then convert them to floating objects. I am trying to use a regular expression to replace these strings but I am having difficulty. The column name is 'cease_date' and the DF is called 'dete_resignations'.

```
pattern2 = r"(?P<cease_date>[1-2][0-9]{3})?"
years = dete_resignations['cease_date'].str.extractall(pattern2)
print(years['cease_date'].value_counts())
2013    146
2012    129
2014     22
2010      2
2006      1
```

So from the above the regular expression works, but I have no idea how to get it back into the original dataframe. I tried doing a boolean index but it didn't work. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to extract the last four digits in your strings:

```
 years = dete_resignations['cease_date'].str.extract('(\d{4})$')[0]
```

Comment: Hmm when I do this, I get the error "pattern contains no capture groups". Also if this creates a new variable 'years', how do I get this to replace the values in the 'cease date' column?

Comment: Thanks, that brings up the following error:
KeyError: 0

Comment: Please note that I used `extract` and pattern is not named. If you use named pattern (`?P<name>`), then you should the the corresponding name instead of `0`.